# Teradata connection working for one site but not for the other

Tags: asp.net, connection, odbc, teradata

I have configured a Teradata driver and connecting to TD from one website which works fine. But when we try to connect to TD using the same driver through a different website hosted on the same server I'm getting following error:

> ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found. (Teradata, D:\Apps\Program Files\Teradata\Client\14.10\ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664\Lib\tdata32.dll). 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]: ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The specified module could not be found. (Teradata, D:\Apps\Program Files\Teradata\Client\14.10\ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664\Lib\tdata32.dll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DSN was missing on the other server and that's what was causing this error. Hope it would be helpful to someone.